# Starting an SBT project in IntelliJ IDEA 13.0.2 Ultimate (build #UI-133.696): clarification needed

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

**Setup:**

- I created a new SBT project in IntelliJ IDEA 13.0.2 Ultimate (Fig. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUjfP.png)).
- I named the project "test" (Fig. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUjfP.png)).
- After creation, Fig. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPJvP.png) shows the project directory structure.

I have three main questions:

**Question 1:**

- None of the source folders (shown in Fig. [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPTFC.png)) were generated by IDEA 13.

  - Should I create src/main/scala (and others) by hand ?

**Question 2:**

- What is the difference between the two modules created ("test"- Fig. [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjFlT.png) and "test-build" - Fig. [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPTFC.png)) ?

  - Which one should I use ?
  - I assume test, but what is the purpose of test-build then?

**Question 3:**

- What is the meaning of "target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main" source
  folder in the "test" module (Fig. [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjFlT.png))?

  - What should I use that for ?
  - What kind of sources should go there ?

Thanks for reading.

[image: Creating SBT project.]

[image: Directory structure after creating an SBT project.]

[image: Modules.]

[image: test module]

[image: test-build module]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> None of the source folders (shown in Fig. 5) were generated by IDEA 13.

You don't need them for proper SBT work and hence SBT doesn't insist on them available (and perhaps that's the reason why IDEA doesn't create them by default).

> Should I create src/main/scala (and others) by hand ?

Nope. You will eventually, but for now you don't need to bother. Scala sources can go to the main directory of the project and SBT will see them.

There's a caveat however - you'll have to use `New > File` to create Scala files as the main directory is not marked as `Sources root`.

> What is the difference between the two modules created ("test"- Fig. 4 and "test-build" - Fig. 5) ?

`test` is your project while `test-build` is the build configuration's project. [SBT is recursive](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html#sbt-is-recursive).

> Which one should I use ?

`test`

> I assume test, but what is the purpose of test-build then?

See [sbt is recursive](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html#sbt-is-recursive) and read the entire [Getting Started](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/index.html).

> What is the meaning of "target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main" source folder in the "test" module (Fig. 4)?
>   What should I use that for ?
>   What kind of sources should go there ?

It's SBT's output directory and you should not worry about it for now.

I strongly advise reading the entire [Getting Started](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/index.html) to get you going with SBT.

Comment: Thank you Jacek for the detailed answer !